# Membership login page just sends members back to homepage

Tags: redirect, authentication

Members of my website are supposed to be sent to a members' directory after successfully entering their login information.  However, after hitting the "Login" button, they are all sent back to the homepage of my site.

There have been some recent changes in my site, which probably is the cause, but I can't figure out what it could be.  I have NOT touched the login coding at all.

The login page I'm referring to is http://www.teleworkrecruiting.com/page25.html

Any feedback would be so appreciated.

Thank you,
Pamela

CODE:

```
 <div id="Ggeo768" class="dfltc">
<h1 align="center"> <font face="arial">Login Required </font></h1>
<div align="center"><FONT face="Arial">Members, log in to access the latest hiring        companies and 
jobs.<BR>
</FONT> <font face="Arial">If you are not a registered user, <a      href="telecommute.html">  CLICK HERE</a> 

and sign up for access!</font></div>
<p align="center">
<form method="post" action="/"dir09.php">

<div align="center">User ID: 
 <input type="text" name="uid" size="8" />
<br /><br>
Password: 
 <input type="password" name="pwd" SIZE="8" />
<br /><br>
<input type="submit" value="Log in" />
</div>
</form>
<div align="center"></p> </div>
 </body>

</html></div>
</div>

<div id="Oobj590" style="position:absolute;z-index:7;visibility:visible;           left:563px;top:25px;width:158px;height:65px;">
<div id="Grtf591" class="dfltt">
<div align="center"><font face="Arial" class="fsx05" color="#ffffff">         <B>Telecommuting<br>
Job Seekers<br>
<a href="telecommute.html"><font color="#ffffff">Click Here</font></a><br></B></font>    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="Oobj1325" style="position:absolute;z-index:8;visibility:visible;    left:275px;top:824px;width:400px;height:19px;">
 <div id="Grtf608" class="dfltt">
<div align="center"><font face="Arial" class="fsx01" color="#ff0000">Lost your     username or password?&nbsp; </font><font face="Arial" class="fsx01">Write to <a         href="mailto:admin@teleworkrecruiting.com?subject=Lost username or password"          title="Administrator">admin@teleworkrecruiting.com</a><br></font></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Lots and lots of possible causes. Can you at least post the code which executes upon successful login?

Comment: Totally agree with @AljoshaBre. The culprit must be in `/dir09.php`. Please post the code from that file and we can help you. Note that there may be some sensitive code in there that you *may* want to exclude.

Comment: Sure, thank you for taking the time to look.

Comment: Here is the code that always worked:

Comment: Hmmm...I'm unable to post because there are too many characters.  How can I post it here?

Comment: Now, the page that non-members were to go to was "telecommute.html". That page has been changed to "Where_to_find_telecommuting_jobs.html". However, I attempted to change that in the coding on a test page, but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: @PamelaJLaGioia Edit your original post and add your code in there :)

Comment: @PamelaJLaGioia If you notice above, I was looking for the code in `dir09.php` page...This is an extract from `page25.html` which is not useful...

Comment: There is no code for that page.  It is just a page.  The only thing unique to that page is the "No follow" snippet.

Answer (score 0):

(following up on the comments above)

In `page25.html`, notice the declaratin of the `form` tag:

`<form method="post" action="/"dir09.php">` - there is an extra apostrophe in the `action` attribute! Replace it with this:

`<form method="post" action="/dir09.php">`

Comment: Okay, I think I understand a little. I was able to copy the entire page in html. it is very long.  Can I send it to you personally?

Comment: Before we do that, look for the following in `dir09.php`: `header("Location:` **or** `http_redirect`. This is how one would initiate a redirect in PHP. If you find it, simply change the destination page after the "Location:" string.

Comment: Let me ask you; if you go to http://www.teleworkrecruiting.com/dir90.php are you able to enter the directory?

Comment: Ahhh - I see the problem now...In `page25.html`, notice the declaratin of the `form` tag: `<form method="post" action="/"dir09.php">` there is an extra apostrophe in the `action` attribute! Replace it with this: `<form method="post" action="/dir09.php">`

Comment: It worked for me!!!!!  Thank you so much!  Why did that have not effect on logging in before, tho?

Comment: It could have been because you used a different browser or perhaps the editing software updated it "for you" (assuming you're the only one working on the site). Please upvote and tag the question as answered :) Cheers

Comment: Listen, may I please give you a membership to my web site?  If you are ever interested in this type of work (for extra money, or whatever it may be), we have a nice IT-Computer/Web category listing companies that hire home-based programmers and whatever else.  I so appreciate your help!

Comment: :) why not! lkaradashkov *at* gmail,

Comment: Many thanks.  I also tried to upvote using those arrows. Did I do that right?  Best,